# Extract json informations

Tags: java, android, json, facebook

I'am using **Facebook sdk** for android and I want to know if there is json library included,
this is my returned json string, how can I extract UID ?

```
{
    "id": "111513307",
    "name": "kevin Zhioua",
    "first_name": "kevin",
    "last_name": "Zhioua",
    "link": "http://www.facebook.com/kevin.zhioua",
    "username": "kevin.zhioua",
    "gender": "male",
    "email": "mimo23_est@hotmail.com",
    "timezone": 1,
    "locale": "fr_FR",
    "verified": true,
    "updated_time": "2011-11-14T17:42:27+0000"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an available [library](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) in Android to handle JSON, you may use it like this:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(theStringFromFacebook);
String uid = jobj.getString("id");
```

P.S - don't forget to `import org.json.JSONObject;`

Answer (score 0):

Android includes the [JSON-java](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) library, but you can also use [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/) is a tutorial i have written some time ago to help you use GSON to parse such JSONs.

Please let me know if you find it handy!